# How can I convert a pd.Series to a dask-backed xr.DataArray?

Tags: python-xarray

I have data as `pd.Series` with `pd.MultiIndex`:

- 1–8 dimensions (index levels),
- 1–500 labels along each dimension,
- ~5–20 million total elements in the Cartesian product of those labels, but
- less than 1% full.

I would like to convert these data to `xr.DataArray`.

Here's some example code that produces an `pd.Series` with 377 elements of a possible 73,984,365—only 0.00051% full.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Dimensions and their lengths
dims = 'abcdef'
sizes = [1, 5, 21, 21, 89, 377]

# Names like f_000 … f_376 along each dimension
coords = []
for d, N in zip(dims, sizes):
    coords.append([f'{d}_{i:03d}' for i in range(N)])

def make_values():
    """Make a DataFrame containing each label in *coords* at least once."""
    values = list(zip_longest(*coords, np.random.rand(max(sizes))))
    result = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=list(dims) + ['value']) \
               .ffill() \
               .set_index(list(dims))
    return result

data = make_values()
```

It is not possible to `xr.DataArray.from_series(data)`, and then `.chunk(…)` the result, because the creation step (using `xr.Dataset.from_dataframe()` internally) creates the full Cartesian product, and produces `MemoryError`.

I have tried:

1. Pre-allocate memory using `xr.DataArray(dask.array.full(fill_value=None, shape=sizes), …)`—but this produces a read-only object, and I cannot assign it values from `data`.
2. Writing to file, somewhat like:

   ```py
   import xarray as xr

   store = pd.HDFStore('temp.h5')
   store.put('foo', data)

   xr.open_dataset('temp.h5', chunks={})  # or with engine='h5netcdf'
   ```

   …but this raises exceptions.

Is there any way to do this short of manually creating a file in one of the formats recognized by `xarray`?

Comment: xarray doesn't currently handle sparse data well. see the conversation here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1375. Is there a reason you want to use xarray rather than pandas/dask.dataframe?

Comment: @delgadom yes, thank you. I've been subscribed to that issue, but no updates in almost a year.

One reason to use `xarray` is to make use of `DataArray.attrs` to carry things like units and other metadata through long/complex calculation pipelines. With `pd.Series` we'd have to do this in an ad-hoc way—not great.

My question could be of broader interest, too, for people wanting to create (rather than read from file) larger-than-memory but _non_-sparse DataArray/Dataset.

Comment: Yeah adding sparse support would be ideal. One thing you could do is `series.to_frame(name="myvar").reset_index().to_xarray()`. This will give you a Dataset indexed positionally with the previous indices as data vars (you could promote to coords). Not a real fix but this is what I've used in the past for applications like this.

Comment: Probably worth noting here that, while dask can support sparse arrays, xarray cannot currently, even when using the dask backend. So even if you allocated a sparse dask array from your series (see e.g. https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2562) you would still blow up your memory at some point when using xarray. So unless you're really asking how to create a larger-than-memory on-disk representation of only a couple MB of data, I don't think this will work for the time being without resorting to tricks.